# Flutter/dart: How to handle custom url scheme callback

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

I'm trying to add Login functionality with Okta Apis in Flutter. In Okta, after the authenticating with username and password it returns a sessionToken which I have to exchange it with authorization api to get api_token.

Here is how the url looks like

```
https://dev-test.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize?response_type=token&scope=openid&state=TEST&nonce=TEST&client_id=asdasasdasd&redirect_uri=com.okta.dev-test:/callback&sessionToken=201111ajXZ86MYTJAqGlo9SJrGN02sTRE364aBkmnBVFLq1lX0c7TL3
```

I have a custom url scheme configured to my app in IOS -> com.okta.dev-test

So once the call is sent, it redirects to the redirectUri where it posts the api_token

```
com.okta.dev-test:/callback#access_token=eyJraWQiOiJ0Z0EzRERrQU9UaFZfU3g4bXZtOEdFOURtXzhZSGlMZEwzaDQtRzlOQW8wIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJ2ZXIiOjEsImp0aSI6IkFULkNOYkE0OC1DUHRuNVBzSDNwVHR1dHg1VDlyRVA0U0pydkNFMWkzbnJNVTAiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi01NTEzODAub2t0YS5jb20vb2F1dGgyL2RlZmF1bHQiLCJhdWQiOiJhcGk6Ly9kZWZhdWx0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTcxNDQxNTU3LCJleHAiOjE1NzE0NDUxNTcsImNpZCI6IjBvYTFpcHZlYTVtYURCenBFMzU3IiwidWlkIjoiMDB1MWx4M2E4b1pVVFRFNFUzNTciLCJzY3AiOlsib3BlbmlkIl0sInN1YiI6InByYXZpbmFyckBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.S9git7PzJF0RpIxULiSAmQFWkNlhG8KvwUZm8UDR68mNgVoUnfK5rXplO3tXZVRxLyzmcFgCXgU36lWc2-hOWF9NUWvgxf7PAmfdNKjdbveMvZmqyNPuiOcDDVvV-h6C0DYgTAo_5VSMPvTI0QerVmgOQ61yYmi12UH319T7OHirsEN1RhIS1ztHLj0CQuXtmSJoX-C5Ko7Mr3PbRkY6OxmgFbyDuTtxWxqTbn5JHXbNggozs48I_nIwurQOLSq8MGAeaUBToiqCfZNhciqpBpEtmJgg4sck-oZsiyA_ZB8HYpBhTmiJNVUsK4Ln6DsI4m2n3RnRd-DuE-KJnDDm7Q&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=openid&state=TEST
```

Now, when I open this url in a webview,it was able to recognize the url scheme and post the message there. But when I tried to use the http.get to call the url it would error out saying

```
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI com.okta.dev-test:/callback)
```

Is there a way to get the access token from the callback and solve this issue using http get? Or is there any other way to achieve this without using a webview ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use a Uri to make the call? http.get(Uri.http(...)) https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-core/Uri-class.html

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

To handle URL scheme on iOS, first ensure that deep linking is [configured](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking#enable-deep-linking-on-ios) for iOS. The reason why the error is thrown is because there's nothing configured in you app that can handle `com.okta.dev-test:/callback`. To handle this path, you need to configure `/callback` in your [Routes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Router-class.html).